# finding all possible longest increasing subsequence using recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking, lis, recursive-backtracking

I tried to find all possible longest increasing subsequence using recursion. When I tried an input array `{10,22,9,33,21,50,41,40,60,55}`, it worked and the output was:

```
10 22 33 40 55 /
10 22 33 41 55 /
10 22 33 50 55 /
10 22 33 40 60 /
10 22 33 41 60 /
10 22 33 50 60 /
```

But when I tried an input array `{2,-3,4,90,-2,-1,-10,-9,-8}`, I got an output:

```
-3 4 90 /
-3 -2 -1 /
-10 -9 -8 /
```

In this case I didn't get `2 4 90`. What should I change in my code to make it word for this case?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[]={10,22,9,33,21,50,41,40,60,55};
        int lis[]=new int[arr.length];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            lis[i]=1;
        }
        for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
                if(arr[i]>arr[j]&&lis[i]<lis[j]+1){
                    lis[i]=lis[j]+1;
                }
            }
        }
        int max=0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(max<lis[i])
                max=lis[i];
        }
        //**************Recursive Print LIS****************
        int rIndex=-1;
        for(int i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            if(lis[i]==max){
                 rIndex=i;
                 break;
            }
        }
        int res[]=new int[max];
        printLISRecursive(arr,rIndex,lis,res,max,max);
    }

    private static void printLISRecursive(int[] arr, int maxIndex, int[] lis, int[] res, int i, int max) {
        if(maxIndex<0)return;
        if(max==1&&lis[maxIndex]==1&&i==1){
            res[i-1]=arr[maxIndex];
//            System.out.println("Using Print Recursion:");
            for(int j=0;j<res.length;j++){
                System.out.print(res[j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            return;
        }
        if(lis[maxIndex]==max){
            res[i-1]=arr[maxIndex];
            printLISRecursive(arr, maxIndex-1, lis, res, i-1, max-1);
        }
        printLISRecursive(arr, maxIndex-1, lis, res, i, max);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm tempted to answer: the algorithm. Your code looks very complicated. Why are you passing 3 array as parameters ?

Comment: Why is (2, 40, 90) correct answer, when there is actually (2, -3, 4, 90) in the input sequence?

Comment: Ah, I see, You don't need continuous sequence, sorry.

Comment: for:  int arr[] = {2, -3, 4, 90, -2, -1, -10, -9, -8}; i got: -10 -9 -8 /
-3 -2 -8 /
-3 4 -8 /
-3 -2 -1 /
-3 4 -1 /
-3 4 90 /
and I just copy paste your algorithm;

Comment: -3 -2 -8 / -3 4 -8 /  -3 4 -1 is not increasing subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int lcsrec(String x, String y) {

    // If one of the strings has one character, search for that character
    // in the other string and return the appropriate answer.
    if (x.length() == 1) 
      return find(x.charAt(0), y);
    if (y.length() == 1)
      return find(y.charAt(0), x);

    // Solve the problem recursively.

    // Corresponding beginning characters match.
    if (x.charAt(0) == y.charAt(0))
      return 1+lcsrec(x.substring(1), y.substring(1));

    // Corresponding characters do not match.
    else 
      return max(lcsrec(x,y.substring(1)), lcsrec(x.substring(1),y));

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String  lcs(String  a, String  b){
    int aLen = a.length();
    int bLen = b.length();
    if(aLen == 0 || bLen == 0){
        return "";
    }else if(a.charAt(aLen-1) == b.charAt(bLen-1)){
        return lcs(a.substring(0,aLen-1),b.substring(0,bLen-1))
            + a.charAt(aLen-1);
    }else{
        String  x = lcs(a, b.substring(0,bLen-1));
        String  y = lcs(a.substring(0,aLen-1), b);
        return (x.length() > y.length()) ? x : y;
    }
}
```